# UITest MacOS Click to MenuBar app not work

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I try create simple UITest for my MacOS MenuBar app. Test case: Just click to app icon, click to "Customize stations ..." then check stations more than 2 exist in table.

```
    func testStationsExistInTable() {
      let app = XCUIApplication()
      let menuBarsQuery = app.menuBars
      menuBarsQuery.children(matching: .statusItem).element(boundBy: 0).click()
      menuBarsQuery.menuItems["Customize Stations ..."].click()
      XCTAssertTrue(app.windows["Preferences"].cells.count > 2)
    }
```

When I try run this test case and **move mouse** to MenuBar - test is pass. But when I just run it and not touch mouse it fail.

Error:
[image]

> Element is not hittable and is not in a scroll view: StatusItem, {{-576.0, -22.0}, {30.0, 22.0}}

My questions is how I can move focus in UITest to MenuBar? And test should pass w/o my mouse movements.